# Quotes within quotes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I'm trying to create an array of values within an input field.  However, the values need to have quotes and I'm having a hard time with quotes canceling each other out.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead"
       data-source='[<% @results.each do |result| %>"<%= result['name'] %>",<% end %>]'>
```

My issue is that I have either two sets of `"` or `'`.  When I try something like `result[name]` without the quotes I get the error: undefined local variable or method `name'.

Updated as I need data-source to have the ''s and data inside to have the ""s

How can I get around this?

Comment: Why not save everyone issues and create the value outside of the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="[<%= @results.map { |r| "'#{r['name']}'" }.join(',') %>]">
```

In IRB this is what happens

```
>> results = [{'name' => "abc"}, {'name' => "fds"}]
=> [{"name"=>"abc"}, {"name"=>"fds"}]
>> results.map { |r| "'#{r['name']}'" }.join(',')
=> "'abc','fds'"
```

Comment: thanks. really close. the only thing is I need the inverse. data-source='' and everything in between in ""s. i.e. data-source='["hello", "goodbye"]'

Comment: thx, sorry for being so bad on this...but now has data-source='['hello', 'goodbye']' instead of the desired data-source='["hello", "goodbye"]'

Comment: that wont work. That's not valid HTML. You can do `data-source="['hello', 'goodbye']"` or `data-source='["hello", "goodbye"]'`. And I recommend the first one

Comment: the second one is what bootstrap is requiring unfortunately.  how would i do the second?  thank you!

Comment: `<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='[<%= @results.map { |r| '"' + r['name'] + '"' }.join(',') %>]'>`

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write that as something like this:

```
   <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="[<%= @results.each {|result| result['name']} %>">
```

Note this code is not tested.

Essentially the result of evaluating the ruby block inside of the beestings should be the desired string - you shouldn't need to do any nesting of beestings.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" data-source='<%= @results.collect(&:name).to_json %>' data-provide="typeahead">
```

the quotes around attributes are optional in html5